# How do I scrape when there are multiple 'p' tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape a website that has multiple `<p>` tags which will always start with the words "Located in:...". None of the other `<p>` tags start with these words.

How do I get my scraper to extract only those particular tags?

This is scraper.rb:

```
 require 'open-uri'
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'csv'

    # Store URL to be scraped
    url = "http://www.timeout.com/london/restaurants/the-50-best-street-food-stalls-in-london?package_page=68111"
    # Parse the page with Nokogiri
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

    # Display output onto the screen
    name =[]
    page.css('h3').each do |line|
      name << h3.text.strip
    end

    zero =[]
    page.css('p').each do |line|
      zero << line.text.strip
    end
```

This is the incoming HTML to be scraped:

```
      <div class="feature-item__text">

      <h3>
     Yu Kyu
      </h3>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <p class="feature_item__annotation--truncated">
    <p>Everybody knows that on any given visit to...</p>
    <p><strong>Don't miss:</strong> Curry Katsu Sandwich (&pound;6.50).</p>
    <p><strong>Find them at:</strong><a href="http://www.timeout.com/london/restaurants/kerb">Kerb</a>.</p>
    <p><strong>But first check:</strong> <a href="...">@_YuKyu_</a></p>
</p>
                                                                                                            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="listing_meta_controls"></div>    
    </article>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]". It's important that you provide a _minimal_ example of your incoming HTML with your _minimal_ code demonstrating the problem. Your text says you are concerned with `<p>` tags but your code shows you are also looking for `<h3>` tags. While we can make a guess at the HTML, odds are good we won't get it right, so help us help you.

Comment: apologies, i will add this now

Comment: The URL you gave says the page doesn't exist.

Comment: please try this: http://www.timeout.com/london/restaurants/the-50-best-street-food-stalls-in-london?package_page=68111

Comment: Instead of putting the new URL in a comment, amend your question and add it in the appropriate place. As is, you make anyone helping you read the question and all comments, instead of only your question.

Comment: its the same URL as before, i think you copy-pasted it incorrectly earlier. i started to edit my original question but stopped when i realised this.

Comment: Nowhere in your example HTML, or in the URL that you gave, is the word `"Located"`, let alone `"Located in:..."`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your question and how it aligns with the HTML.

It's possible the site is changing wording to throw off scrapers and changing "Located in:" to "Find them at". If so probably you can't trust that as a waypoint when locating the information you want.

That said, CSS doesn't allow us to look for text starting with something, but XPath does:

```
@doc.search('//strong[starts-with(text(), "Find")]/following-sibling::a')
```

That selector will locate all `<strong>Find them at:</strong>` tags and adjoining sibling `<a>` tags, allowing you to process the `text` or `'href'` parameter of the tag, depending on what you want. Using that selector I see 84 hits on the page, which look like:

```
@doc.search('//strong[starts-with(text(), "Find")]/following-sibling::a').first.to_html 
#=> "<a href=\"http://www.timeout.com/london/restaurants/kerb\">Kerb</a>"

@doc.search('//strong[starts-with(text(), "Find")]/following-sibling::a').first.text 
#=> "Kerb"
@doc.search('//strong[starts-with(text(), "Find")]/following-sibling::a').first['href'] 
#=> "http://www.timeout.com/london/restaurants/kerb"
```

If you want to use CSS, it's possible but you have to take a different tactic. Look for the containing `<div>` and then search inside:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

URL = 'http://www.timeout.com/london/restaurants/the-50-best-street-food-stalls-in-london?package_page=68111'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL))
feature_items = doc.search('div.feature-item__text').map{ |div|
  h3 = div.at('h3').text.strip
  a = div.at('strong + a')
  a_text = a.text.strip
  a_href = a['href']

  {
    h3: h3,
    a_text: a_text,
    a_href: a_href
  }
}
```

This returns an array of hashes, each hash would be the information for a particular place.

Here's the first five found:

```
feature_items[0, 5]
# => [{:h3=>"Yu Kyu",
#      :a_text=>"Kerb",
#      :a_href=>"http://www.timeout.com/london/restaurants/kerb"},
#     {:h3=>"Luardos",
#      :a_text=>"Kerb",
#      :a_href=>"http://www.timeout.com/london/restaurants/kerb"},
#     {:h3=>"Mission Mariscos",
#      :a_text=>"The Schoolyard",
#      :a_href=>"http://www.timeout.com/london/shopping/broadway-market-1"},
#     {:h3=>"Butchies",
#      :a_text=>"Broadway Market",
#      :a_href=>"http://www.timeout.com/london/shopping/broadway-market-1"},
#     {:h3=>"BBQ Dreamz",
#      :a_text=>"Kerb",
#      :a_href=>"http://www.timeout.com/london/restaurants/kerb"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you can simply do

```
zero =[]
page.css('p').each do |line|
   text = line.text.strip
   if text.present? && text.include? 'Located in'
     zero << text
   end
end
```

Comment: I get this error when I run your code:  'syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
   if text.present? && text.include? 'Located in'
                                      ^
fxrates_scraper.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input'